# System time messed up after booting from Linux flash-drive

Tags: windows-8, ubuntu-12.04, time

I had recently installed Edubuntu 12.04 LTS onto a flash drive and have started booting from it. Since then, every time I reboot my system after using Edubuntu, my Windows time is four hours later than it is supposed to be. Sooner or later, it fixes itself (most likely by synchronizing with the Internet), but it could be a bit annoying sometimes when it messes up f.lux. How can I fix this?

Comment: It resets even after you correct the time zone?

Comment: I have this problem as well, every time I boot into Fedora instead of Windows. One word of advice; DON'T open up Skype before your clock syncs to the correct time or your conversations will be majorly screwed up.

Comment: @Ramhound It is corrected after I change back manually or Internet time syncs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows by default assume the BIOS time is the local time, while Linux by default assume the BIOS time is UTC. So the solution is either to :

- Tell Windows to use UTC

Make a .REG files in Notepad, containing

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation]
 "RealTimeIsUniversal"=dword:00000001
```

Double click the file to integrate the setting, you'll probably need to restart.

- Tell Linux to use local time

Open `/etc/default/rcS` as root, find `UTC=yes`, change it to `UTC=no` and restart